# NSMutableArray in playground causing errors with Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, swift-playground

I have a class that gets all the country codes and is supposed to sort them alphabetically. The class runs fine in Xcode for ios but when I copy it to test it in playground I get an error. See picture.

[image: Playground code]

So I stripped back all the code to find the NSMutableArray wasn't declared properly so it changed them to this.

```
var countries:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var countryKeys:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var countryNames:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
```

It took away the error but the code wont run. No errors and no output.

Anyone know why this code won't run in playground? Is it a bug?

Full code here

```
struct countryCodes{
    var countries:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var countryKeys:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var countryNames:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    init(){
        for code in NSLocale.ISOCountryCodes() {
            let id = NSLocale.localeIdentifierFromComponents([NSLocaleCountryCode: code])
            let name = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_UK").displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: id) ?? "Country not found for code: \(code)"
            self.countries.addObject(["key":id,"value":name])
        }
        self.sortByValue()
    }

    private func sortByValue(){
        let descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "value", ascending: true)
        extractToArrays(self.countries.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor]))
    }

    private func extractToArrays(sortedCountries:NSArray){
        for item in self.countries{
            self.countryKeys.addObject(item["key"] as! String)
            self.countryNames.addObject(item["value"] as! String)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried opening a new playground and Immediately I get an error

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"
```

The error

file:///Volumes/External/Xcode%20Projects/MyPlayground3.playground/: error: Playground execution aborted: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8).

Comment: Please post your code so we can test it.

Comment: Works for me ([screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s236/sh/464f0ce3-85ce-42a2-a659-dd58fc0c834f/9a2422be9ec8fca6/res/4a5d37ba-a155-4685-8e61-3edb872940e0/skitch.png))...

Comment: Why are you using `NSMutableArray` instead of a Swift array? I think it's making this harder than it needs to be.

Comment: @EricD. Can't view your screenshot. I don't have an evernote account. Interesting why it doesn't run on my playground. Could it be some sort of configuration problem?

Comment: @AlMartin [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e04oeq3pzi90hwo/IOS-S2_playground.png?dl=0)

Comment: @AaronBrager. That's the reason I want it in Playground to improve it. If I can get it working. Haha.

Comment: I just tried opening a new playground.. see the edit.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly on my playground. Are you using Xcode 7 beta ?

Comment: Version 7.0 beta 6 (7A192o)

Comment: Update to GM. Problem solved.

Comment: What's the difference between 7.1 Beta and 7.0 GM?

Comment: The main difference is that 7.1 allows you create apps for tvOS. I guess there is plenty more, check out the release notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments.

First, value names should begin with capital letters:

```
struct CountryCodes {
```

Steer clear of untyped collections like `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`. Just use the native Swift collection types. So `countries` will be an array of `[String : String]`:

```
    var countries = [[String : String]]()
```

In initialization, we need to create the array, and sort it.

```
    init() {
        for code in NSLocale.ISOCountryCodes() {
            let id = NSLocale.localeIdentifierFromComponents([NSLocaleCountryCode : code])
```

Swift Optionals represent whether or not data is there. So in the case that data is *not* there, it's a bad practice to insert a string saying so in your data model. Instead, use `guard` to handle that case:

```
            guard let name = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_UK").displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: id) else {
                debugPrint("Country not found for code: \(code)")
                break;
            }
```

Once you get the keys and values, append them to the array of countries:

```
            countries += [["key":id, "value":name]]
        }
```

Now that you have all of them, sort by value:

```
        countries = countries.sort() { $0["value"] < $1["value"] }
    }
```

Calculating keys and country names can quickly be done using `map` - no need to store them in separate arrays:

```
    var keys : [String] {
        return countries.map { $0["key"]! }
    }

    var names : [String] {
        return countries.map { $0["value"]! }
    }
}
```

Here's the full code if you want to try it in a playground:

```
struct CountryCodes {
    var countries = [[String : String]]()

    init() {
        for code in NSLocale.ISOCountryCodes() {
            let id = NSLocale.localeIdentifierFromComponents([NSLocaleCountryCode : code])

            guard let name = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_UK").displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: id) else {
                debugPrint("Country not found for code: \(code)")
                break;
            }

            countries += [["key":id, "value":name]]
        }

        countries = countries.sort() { $0["value"] < $1["value"] }
    }

    var keys : [String] {
        return countries.map { $0["key"]! }
    }

    var names : [String] {
        return countries.map { $0["value"]! }
    }
}

let codes = CountryCodes()
codes.countries
codes.keys
codes.names
```

Notice that this code uses no forced casting (`as!`) which causes crashes due to logical errors. The only force operator (`!`) being used is in the `keys` and `names` getters.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll test it out when I can get my playground working.

Comment: After downloading the latest Xcode 7 beta I'm glad to say it now works. So does your code. You also fixed the issue I was having with it not sorting the names alphabetically. Thank you..